# Catching an exception thrown in a Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I need to know if an exception that happens inside a method called by a Thread can be catch in the main application. 
I'm doing a Windows forms application and one of the things I have to do is store some data in a database, but I need to inform the user if, for some reason, the operation was unsuccessful (e.g if the application couldn't connect to the database). The thing is that I have to call the method to insert the values in the DB from a new Thread, and, therefore, I use the try;catch blocks from inside that method. But if an error occur and the exception is thrown there is nobody able to catch it so the program crashes. 
I have been doing some google search but all that I could find recommended to use the class Task instead of Thread, but, because this is an assignment from my university, I need to use Threads.

So, is there a way to "transfer" the exception from a Thread to the main thread of the application ? Here's my code so far:

```
    //This is how I create the new Thread
    public static Correo operator +(Correo c, Paquete p)
    {
        foreach (Paquete paq in c.Paquetes)
        {
            if (paq == p)
                throw new TrackingIDRepetidoException("El paquete ya se encuentra cargado en la base de datos");
        }
        c.Paquetes.Add(p);
        Thread hilo = new Thread(p.MockCicloDeVida);
        hilo.Start();
        c.mockPaquetes.Add(hilo);
        return c; 
    }


    public void MockCicloDeVida()
    {
        while (this.Estado != EEstado.Entregado)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            this.Estado += 1;
            this.InformaEstado(this, new EventArgs());
        }
        try
        {
            // A simple method to insert an object in a DB. The try catch to check if the connection to the DB was succesfull or not is implemented here.
            PaqueteDAO.Insertar(this);
        }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException e)
        {
            // I can't catch the exception here
        }
    }
```

Any help or tips is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using a `Thread` rather than a `Task`?

Comment: `Thread` is for fire-and-forget threads where you do not want any response from the thread, including if it got an error. If you want a response you should use a `BackgroundWorker` or `Task`.

Comment: It's an assignment from my university, they force me to use Threads.

Comment: Eseentially, no.  Exceptions are a stack-based mechanism and each thread has its own stack.

Comment: That's going to be painful; you'll have to use IPC like pipes or message queues. You may be able to build something from `WaitHandle`s; I wouldn't want to.

Comment: Let's say you could get the exception information back to the main thread. How would you catch it? Do you want it to interrupt whatever the main thread was working on? Or do you want things to keep going, but to get the exception logged, for example? Or set a variable to influence flow of control? Obviously you can't use a `catch` block in the traditional way.

Comment: @JohnWu The idea is only to inform the user that the insert to the DB failed, and nothing else. Like with a MessaBox.Show and nothing more than that.

Comment: Invote/BeginInvoke a copy of the the exception object or message.

Answer (score 1):

I would use this very useful class: [TaskCompletionSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
var th = new Thread(() => MockCicloDeVida(tcs));
th.Start();
try
{
    var returnedObj = tcs.Task.Result;
}
catch(AggregateException aex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(aex.InnerExceptions.First().Message);
}
```

---

```
public void MockCicloDeVida(TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs )
{
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
    tcs.TrySetException(new Exception("something bad happened"));
    //tcs.TrySetResult(new SomeObject());
}
```